# How to filter document by a value in the dictionary in arangodb?

Tags: arangodb

I have following structure in arangodb collection named `clientShadow`.

```json
{
  "_class": "com.syncservice.document.ClientShadow",
  "sessions": {
  "session-id-2": {
      "workspaceId": "workspace-id-1",
      "message": {
        "lastSynced": 0,
        "lastAvailable": 1674630705773
      }
    },
    "session-id-1": {
      "workspaceId": "workspace-id-1",
      "message": {
        "lastSynced": 0,
        "lastAvailable": 1674630705773
      }
    },
    "session-id-0": {
      "workspaceId": "workspace-id-1",
      "message": {
        "lastSynced": 0,
        "lastAvailable": 1674630705773
      }
    }
  },
  "synced": true
}
```

Here `sessions` is a map/dictionary of session_id as string and session object as value.

I want to fetch all the sessions from collection where session's `lastSynced` and `lastAvailable` aren't same.

I tried following query

```
FOR doc IN clientShadow
  FOR session IN doc['sessions']
    FILTER session.message.lastSynced != session.message.lastAvailable
    RETURN {'session': session}
```

But I found out that FOR IN works with collections and gives me following error

> Query: AQL: collection or array expected as operand to FOR loop; you provided a value of type 'object' (while executing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retain the original data *and* query structure, don't use `ATTRIBUTES`, use [`VALUES`](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/functions-document.html#values):

```
FOR doc IN clientShadow
  FOR session IN VALUES(doc['sessions'])
    FILTER session.message.lastSynced != session.message.lastAvailable
    RETURN {'session': session}
```

If you cannot change the data structure, you can use [`ATTRIBUTES`](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/functions-document.html#attributes) to access the sessions as array:

Edit: Code as fixed by Kshiti Kshitij Dhakal (Attributes returns a list of the names of the attributes)

```
FOR doc IN clientShadow 
  FOR session IN ATTRIBUTES(doc['sessions']) 
    FILTER 
      doc.sessions[session].message.lastSynced 
        != doc.sessions[session].message.lastAvailable 
    RETURN {'session': doc.sessions[session]}
```

Old (wrong) suggestion:

```
FOR doc IN clientShadow
  FOR session IN ATTRIBUTES(doc['sessions'])
    FILTER session.message.lastSynced != session.message.lastAvailable
    RETURN {'session': session}
```

If you can change the data structure, don't use an object for sessions, but a list:

```
{
  "_class": "com.syncservice.document.ClientShadow",
  "sessions": [
    {
      "sessionId": "session-id-2",
      "workspaceId": "workspace-id-1",
      "message": {
        "lastSynced": 0,
        "lastAvailable": 1674630705773
      }
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, ATTRIBUTES was exactly what I was looking for. How, I needed to make few modifications to get the desired output. Here's final code `FOR doc IN clientShadow FOR session IN ATTRIBUTES(doc['sessions']) FILTER doc.sessions[session].message.lastSynced != doc.sessions[session].message.lastAvailable RETURN {'session': doc.sessions[session]}`

Comment: Also, thanks for the suggestion, I will consider changing the data structure. Do you have any reason for suggesting that? @Tom Regner

Comment: It depends on your use case, really.  If sessions is a list instead of an object, you don't need to call `ATTRIBUTES`. If you need sessions to be a map/dict almost everywhere else, you should probably keep it the way it is.  Total size, indizes, overall performance could dictate another approach altogether.